# a target="_self" is not working in AngularJS ui-router

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router, href

I have a problem that `target="_self"` is redirecting to `otherwise` of `ui-router`

**HTML:**

```
<a target="_self" href="#" class="right_bt" id="activator"><img src="img/landing/menu.png" alt=""/></a>
```

This part of code is a button that will trigger on/off the display of menus.

**App.js**

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
    $stateProvider

    .state("landing", {
        url:"/landing",
        controller: "LandingController",
        templateUrl: "html/landing/index.html"
    })

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

})
```

The problem is it redirects to url `'/'` set in `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise`. Is there a solution to these problem? Thanks.

**UPDATE**
There is nothing wrong with this, because it is not the issue I am thinking of. Sorry.

Comment: try removing `href="#"`.

Comment: Thanks, it works on sample page. But in my project folder with Angularjs, it is not. Maybe theres something wrong with it. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: there is nothing wrong with it. I do use that and it is working fine. What version of `angularjs` and `ui.router` are you using?

Comment: @SibiRaj, Angularjs 1.6.4 and ui-router 0.4.2.yes there's nothing wrong with it. I am thinking it on my included files maybe, probably jquery. Cause showing of the menu is not working on my project but on sample page where get the template, it is working.

Comment: I would also suggest upgrading `ui.router` to the latest version.

Comment: Is your template url correct templateUrl: "html/landing/index.html" ?

Comment: @Vivz, yes it is. Maybe it is the included files in my main `index.html` because there are many js files and css file included in the head and bottom of the body. And I am using `ui-view` in my main `index.html` and this `templateUrl: "html/landing/index.html"` is one of the `view` of my `app` and it also has  js files and css files included. Thinking it is the issue of my problem.

Comment: You are using ui-view in index.html? And again you are referencing it in templateUrl? If so, then change the template in your templateUrl

Comment: @Vivz, No. sorry for not explaining it well. I have a main `index.html` but the one in `templateUrl` is different. Well, I am trying to build a `landing page` and `admin dashboard` so the view is not very much similar and js/css files included is different from `admin dashboard` to `landing page`.

Comment: I am thinking of simple solution that loading/including of js/css files will be dynamically or depends on the `view` or `state` in `ui-router`

Comment: Did you try changing the name of the template to something other than index . Try setting relative path for your templateUrl